# Installing Eclipse IDE on Linux running Raspbian

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, raspbian

I'm struggling with installing Eclipse (for C) on my Raspberry Pi system.  It's only a 32-bit system.  I downloaded the 32-bit compressed file from Eclipse, successfully unzipped it, and get the eclipse-inst file.  But when I try to run it (./eclipse-inst) I get a

bash: ./eclipse-inst: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

when I do file eclipse-inst I get:

eclipse-inst: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=86cbe08f0430c7c05ec016f123d040fb8aad9ffb, with debug_info, not stripped

I have goolged this and have tried everything.  Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure what you downloaded was 32-bit Eclipse for ARM?

Comment: Not the right architecture. Include the output of `file eclipse-inst` in your question and confirm if you have downloaded the right package.

Comment: in the eclipse-installer directory I did:

file eclipse-inst

and got:

eclipse-inst: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=86cbe08f0430c7c05ec016f123d040fb8aad9ffb, with debug_info, not stripped

Comment: That is for Intel x86 processors. You’ll need to get the correct one for the ARM processor in your machine.